# Flutter - Trigger PageView change on Provider value change

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-pageview

I have a custom BottomAppBar with PageView for pages. I am trying to change the pages as the user clicks on items in the BottomAppBar. I am using Provider to manage Global State. Clicking on items triggers the value change in the provider but there is no method in PageView to trigger page change on a value change. How can I achieve this? Below is my code.

My Provider:

```
class CurrentPage extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentPage = 0;
  int get currentPage => _currentPage;

  setCurrentPage(int val) {
    _currentPage = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

A BottomAppBar Item:

```
 InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  context.read<CurrentPage>().setCurrentPage(0);
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 26.5, vertical: 17.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        CustomIcons.home,
                        size: 18.0,
                        color: context.watch<CurrentPage>().currentPage == 0
                            ? Color(0xFF2C1DEB)
                            : Color(0xFFCCCCD5),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 9.0),
                      Text(
                        'HOME',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: context.watch<CurrentPage>().currentPage == 0
                              ? Color(0xFF2C1DEB)
                              : Color(0xFFCCCCD5),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          fontSize: 10.0,
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

PageView:

```
class Pages extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController _pageController =
        PageController(initialPage: context.watch<CurrentPage>().currentPage);

    return PageView(
      onPageChanged: (int) {},
      controller: _pageController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      pageSnapping: true,
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text('Home Page'),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text('Profile Page'),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text('Search Page'),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Text('Jobs Page'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can make it. Once you call `notifyListener` from your provider, if the `currentPage` has changed, this will go to the new selected page

```
class Pages extends StatelessWidget {
      final PageController _pageController =
            PageController(initialPage:0);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Consumer<CurrentPage>(builder:(ctx, currentPage,  widget){

     final pageView = PageView(
          onPageChanged: (int) {},
          controller: _pageController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          pageSnapping: true,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('Home Page'),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text('Profile Page'),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text('Search Page'),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text('Jobs Page'),
            ),
          ],);
          if(currentPage.currentPage != _pageController.page.floor()){
            _pageController.jumpToPage(currentPage.currentPage);
          }
          return pageView;
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. But cant access PageController.page before the pageview is built. Getting below error:

PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.

Comment: Hello Saad. I've updated my answer. please take a look

Comment: That does it. Thanks a ton buddy

Comment: I need help in a similar situation.. Can someone please take a look at this? Thanks in advance...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923192/provider-state-management-for-pagecontroller-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You should use [animateToPage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/animateToPage.html) or [jumpToPage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/jumpToPage.html) methods in PageViewController. also you need to make your Page widget StatefullWidget.

Comment: But how can I trigger any of those on a value change in the provider instead of a button tap?